# How can I achieve 3D sound on ios?

Tags: ios, audio, ios5, openal

I am interested in a way to play sounds from specific points in space relative to the user.

Basically I would like to say the user is at point (0,0) and a sound came from (10,10) and then take a sound and send it through some library that plays it, sounding as though it came from the source (10,10). Performance in doing this would be very important.

If it wasn't painfully obvious from reading the question, I have very little experience with audio on any device.

Comment: @KenWhite Well, in this case it's less a recommendation as a "Does this exist?" sort've question (unless you know of numerous libraries with OP's desired features).  Admittedly, that's not a perfect SO question, but it's not like "What's a good audio library for iOS?"

Comment: @blahdiblah: Then it falls into the "search engine or link site" category, doesn't it? Still not on-topic here. :-)

Comment: sorry that it was sort of a search enginey question. I retitled it so that maybe it is more of a programatic question.

Comment: (For what it is worth... I found this question useful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a little research, it seems the options are to use the OpenAL framework which is supported by apple, or essentially roll your own on top of Audio Unit.

There is a 3D Mixer Audio Unit that apple provides, which requires you to develop a lot of understanding of Audio Units.

Then there is OpenAL which is a cross platform audio framework where you can position a "source" and a "listener" and it will compute attenuation and stereo for you.

Both require low level understanding of playing Audio and are not very fun. So I figured I might as well jump all the way in the water and learn about the Audio Units, since I may want to do some more specialized stuff in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy wrapper for the iOS OpenAL functionality: [ObjectAL-for-iPhone](https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone)

Play around with the example and see if it does what you want.